# Chrome showing autofill box in red, why?

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome is behaving weirdly for some reason. When I start to fill a form and it shows its autofill box, it appears in solid red, making the text unreadable.

[Video of this issue.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qap4kyvponbspan/VID_20200608_113439.mp4?dl=0)

I confirmed the problem still happens when I disable all of my extensions. I confirmed the problem doesn't happen on my other computer, which is synced to the same Google account.

**Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?**

(Chrome version 83.0.4103.61)

Comment: Try again with the default theme.

Comment: @gronostaj Good idea, tried it now with the default theme and it's still happening.

Comment: Hmm. System theme maybe?

Comment: Switching to a light theme fixed it. But: 1. I love my dark theme very much. 2. I have the exact same theme on my other computer, confirmed now they're identical using a diff tool. 3. I haven't changed my dark theme in years, and this bug is new.

Comment: Ah damn, I now upgraded Chrome on the other computer, and the bug is happening there too. Possibly a Chrome bug...

Comment: I reported it now. Hope it gets fixed soon.

Answer (score 0):

1. Launch Google Chrome
2. Go to Settings->Advanced->Accessibility
3. Under the System Tab There is an option called
   Use Hardware Acceleration when available
4. Turn it off if it is on (which was the case for me).
5. Relaunch the Browser.